# Conventional Current

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-current

Recently I learnt about conventional current as well as electron flow, and although electron flow is in the opposite direction to conventional current, we still use conventional current because it makes little difference to our calculations.

Yet when we determine the direction of a magnetic field using the right hand grip rule, we use the direction of current flow. If we are given the direction of conventional current, then isn't the direction of the magnetic field suppose to be in the other direction, because in reality the current is the flow of electrons which is opposite to conventional current.

I think there is something wrong with my logic. What is actually going on here?

Comment: The flow isn't necessarily electrons.

Comment: Our convention for the direction of the magnetic field is just as arbitrary as the direction of the current flow. We have created our model of electromagnetic phenomena in a way that accurately predicts the behavior of the world around us. Arguing about whether the direction of the magnetic field is "actually" opposite to our definition is pointless.

Answer (score 3):

The magnetic field is determined by the conventional current, regardless of the sign of the charge carriers.

It is important to understand that the conventional current is the current. In metals the charge carriers are negative electrons but in semiconductors they can be positive holes, and in electrolytes they can be positive and negative ions at the same time. Similarly with plasmas where both positive and negative charge carriers exist.

Personally, I find the “conventional” in “conventional current” to be distracting and unnecessary. It is just current. The current density is defined as $\vec j =\rho \vec v$ so if the charge density $\rho$ is negative then $\vec j$ simply points in the opposite direction as $\vec v$.

Comment: If conventional current is the actual current then what is electron flow?

Comment: @DominicTorreto The actual current is the motion of charge, regardless of what the charge is composed of. If the charge is positive, the current is in the same direction as its motion. If the charge is negative, the current flows in the opposite direction.

Comment: @DominicTorreto for classical electromagnetism the electron flow is largely irrelevant. The only place it matters in classical electromagnetism is in the Hall effect. Classical electromagnetism was developed before electrons were discovered and so electrons are not necessary for understanding classical electromagnetism

Comment: @Dale I tend to think of vacuum tubes as classical. And I have an old book on vacuum tube electronics that eccentrically defines current flow as electron flow. Thus, it has the "left hand rule" for magnetic fields!

Comment: @JohnDoty I could see it either way. The electron was discovered in 1897, and the cathode ray tube was invented around 1890. So you don’t need electrons for cathode ray tubes. But vacuum tubes were invented in 1904. So I am not sure how they understood them back then. But regardless of the history, they could treat a cathode ray as a continuous charge distribution

Comment: I'm a bit confused. Current is defined to be the rate flow of charge. The charge might be positive or negative. Yet when we use the right hand rule we use conventional current from the positive terminal to the negative terminal. But this is basically a circuit, so electrons are the charge in this case, and hence we should use the current from the negative terminal to positive one, right? Otherwise wouldn't the right hand rule give opposite results?

Comment: @DominicTorreto The current is a mathematical abstraction. If you have a stream of negatively charged particles, the current flows in the opposite direction that the particles move.

Comment: @Dale DeForest was very much a classical physicist, and didn't understand how his invention worked. The theory worked out by Langmuir and others was (and still is) based on pre-quantum atomic physics and statistical mechanics. Electrons play a role, but Planck's constant doesn't.

Comment: @DominicTorreto the magnetic field is determined using the right hand rule with respect to the “conventional” current. Regardless of the sign of the charge carriers.